# send unescaped string with XHR (javascript)

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have string containing javascript file content and I need to upload it to server (it's not part of server side code - it's used only for development (on-site code editing) process so security is not important). PHP script uses `file` and `content` variables. I found only implementations where xhr.send() argument was string in standard GET format (var1=sth&var2=sthelse) but I'd like to send this string without any encoding / decoding / escaping / unescaping on server side. As it's js it contains all possible characters including '&' or '='.

Is it possible to pass data to POST in other way than using standard query?

I'm rather not interested in jQ solution

Comment: Nope. (php exposes POST as a sorted associative array, which is not what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending JS file contents in a query string parameter is not a good idea.  A few points:

- If your situation support HTML5 you can [send files to your server with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).
- If you don't want to send as a file upload I would send it as POST data.
- Any data encoded or escaped on the client can be decoded or unescaped on the server.  In some setups this is automatically done for you.  There's no reason to avoid this if it's the proper way to handle data.

Comment: like i meant - I have js code editor (Ace code editor) embeded on website - my website is downloading files from server - then when I'm opening editor it sets `DEBUG` flag and after it when I'm reloading - it doesn't load files from server but from localStorage (when i'll damage code it loads fallback from server) so after work I'd like to upload modified js from localStorage to files on server - escaping js file will strongly affect on upload size

Comment: who cares about the upload size, you need to get the file there, any file, in one piece, and encoding is the only way to make sure that happens. are you uploading so many edits that bandwidth is an actual problem? that would be an incredible amount of editing on your part! you can DEFLATE the data before base64 encoding it, the results of which with text-based file will usually be smaller than the orig, even after base64ing it...